# limit of a sequence with Lagrange inversion formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

In a recent question to the Pari/GP mailing lists, a user stated that the
limit as $N\to\infty$ of

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\dfrac{n^ne^{-n}}{n!}-\dfrac{2\sqrt{N}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
is equal to $-2/3$. This seems to be an application of Lagrange inversion
and/or the expansion of Lambert's $W$ function around $-1/e$, but I have not been able to find a proof. I would be interested in such a proof.

Comment: I'd say it is Stirling formula in a Cesaro mean

Comment: I think $n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n{e^{-n}\ }(1+1/12n+o(1/n))$ together with $\sum_{n=1}^N {1\over \sqrt{n}}=2\sqrt{N}(1+cn+o(1/n))$ should suffice

Comment: Unfortunately not: Stirling tells us that the expression is equal to some constant $C$ plus an explicit asymptotic expansion in $1/\sqrt{N}$, but does not tell us the constant $C$ itself. This is always the case in Euler-MacLaurin type results.

Comment: You can find an answer to this question in this article http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnuthsSeries.html

Comment: @Peter Heinig In fact the sum in that link is different, although closely related, to the sum in the OP: instead of $ -{2\sqrt{ N}\over \sqrt{2\pi}}$ it has $-\sum_{k=1}^N {1\over \sqrt{2\pi k}}=-{2\sqrt{ N}\over \sqrt{2\pi}} + C + o(1)$  (so they are hopefully both correct)

Answer (score 8):

One way to obtain the -2/3 is by singularity analysis.

The first step is to construct the generating function of your sequence.
From the Taylor expansion of the Lambert $W$ function at 0, one gets that $-W(-x)$ is the generating function of the sequence $N^{N-1}/N!$ and therefore by differentiation
$$\frac{-W(-x)}{1+W(-x)}=\sum_{N\ge1}{\frac{N^N}{N!}x^N}.$$
Replacing $x$ by $x/e$ and multiplying by $1/(1-x)$ yields the desired generating function
$$F(x):=\frac{-W(-x/e)}{(1-x)(1+W(-x/e))}=
\sum_{N\ge1}{\left(\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{n^ne^{-n}}{n!}}\right)x^N}.$$

From there, the result follows from an analysis at $x=1$. From the known expansion of $-W(-x)$ at $1/e$, one deduces
$$F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2(1-x)^{3/2}}-\frac{2}{3(1-x)}+O\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}\right),\quad x\rightarrow1.$$

Now singularity analysis (or Darboux's method) deduces the asymptotic expansion of your sequence as
$$\frac{\sqrt{2 N}}{\sqrt{\pi}}-\frac23+O(1/\sqrt{N}).$$

With slightly more work along the same lines, one obtains a full asymptotic expansion beginning with
$${\frac {\sqrt {2N}}{\sqrt {\pi}}}-\frac23+{\frac {
\sqrt {2}}{3\sqrt {\pi N}}}-{\frac {37\sqrt {2}}{864\sqrt {\pi}N^{3/2}}}+{\frac {359\sqrt {2}
 }{64800\sqrt {\pi}N^{5/2}}}+O \left(  {N}^{-7/2} \right) 
.$$